# multiple variables in a switch case

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it was possible to use two variables in a switch case.

The assignment was to use the same information that I used to create if else statements and but this time use the switch case. The problem is I have two vars that I used to gather the information residence and hours. I am not sure and cannot figure out if you can use these two in a switch. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't you create an array and add the two varible to it and then loop through them?  If you can provide a bit more detail would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, it is an expansion of your question: [if statements blending together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335125/if-statements-blending-together)

If you can't use if statements, you can use nested switch statements.

```js
switch (residence) {
  case "house":
    switch (hours) {
      case 12:
        print(...);
        break;
      ...
      default:
        Assert(false);
    }
  ...
  default:
    Assert(false);
}
```